# How to populate an html input field from url

Tags: html

I thought a html input field could be populated with an url
by using ?fieldname=value  behind the base url
But I am stuck with this all morning now.

this is the part of my html

```
                <tr class="pure-table-odd">
                <td><label for="name">Naam</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" value="" required  id="name" title=""></td>
            </tr>
```

When i make a link with the following url  the field still stays empty. Any suggestion?

```
http://83.163.140.140//web2016/spa_wellness_arrangementen/vriendinnendag_wellness_arrangement.html?name=test
```

ps
Actually I need to check a checkbox. But I thought to try something more 'easy' first

Comment: How are you populating the input field? Or you think that just by using the "name" parameter in url it should automatically populate your input beacuse it's name and id is "name"?

Comment: you are right. I saw this solution in other webpages. I got the answer now, i will look for JS to solve it. Thank you for your response

Comment: check this: http://w3lessons.info/2013/02/25/how-to-get-url-parameters-values-using-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use URL-parameters like that. You will need to either process the request server-side (via PHP or similar), or via javascript. However, processing things like this opens up a lot of other potential security holes, so you should know what you're doing.

In PHP, this would be something like:

```
<?php
echo '<tr class="pure-table-odd">
        <td><label for="name">Naam</label></td>
        <td>';
if ($_GET['parameter']) { //checks if "parameter" exists in the URL string
  $var = $_GET['parameter'];
  echo '<input type="text" name="name" value="'.$var.'" required  id="name" title="">';
}
echo '</td></tr>';

?>
```